# Stuck on Ruby foreach printing text at the end

Tags: ruby, xml, foreach

I'm not sure how to phrase this question but I'm stuck on how to print text after the main loop runs. I'm working with builder to generate some XML.  The issue is I want to print the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<twenty4threshold xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <servicedef>
    <hostname></hostname>
  </servicedef>
  <servicedef>
    <hostname></hostname>
  </servicedef>
  <hours hoursID="1">
  </hours>
  <hours hoursID="2">
  </hours>
</twenty4threshold>
```

Notice how the `hourID`s come at the end But I'm getting the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<twenty4threshold xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <servicedef>
    <hostname></hostname>
  </servicedef>
  <hours hoursID="1">
  </hours>
  <servicedef>
    <hostname></hostname>
  </servicedef>
  <hours hoursID="2">
  </hours>
</twenty4threshold>
```

Which is understandable since I'm printing the text within the foreach loop.  What I don't understand is how to print the hoursID XML statement after the first block for the servicedef.  I was thinking a nested for loop?  I've tried next as well with no luck.  Any advice on what I'm doing wrong appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'builder'

builder = Builder::XmlMarkup.new(:target=>STDOUT, :indent=>2)
builder.instruct! :xml, :version => '1.0', :encoding => 'UTF-8'
builder.twenty4threshold("xmlns:xsi" => "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance") {
  source = File.new "host.txt"
  hid = 0

  source.readlines.each do |access|
    hid = hid += 1;
    builder.servicedef { |b| b.hostname(""); }

    builder.hours(:hoursID => "#{hid}") {  }
  end
```

Comment: checkout this sax parsing options, http://amolnpujari.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/reading_huge_xml-rb/ New OX ruby parser seems to be 5 times faster than Nokogiri, https://gist.github.com/amolpujari/5966431

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading the file and printing `<servicedef>` and `<hours>` for each line. If you want to write all `<servicedef>` tags, then all `<hours>` tags, I suggest you first load the file, remember what you want to remember in an array, then loop through it twice. Something similar to this:

```
lines = source.lines
lines.each do |access|
  builder.servicedef { |b| b.hostname(""); }
end
lines.each do |access|
  hid += 1
  builder.hours(:hoursID => "#{hid}") {  }
end
```

Also note that you're not closing your file. It is a good practice to do your file reading in a block, so your file will autoclose when you want it to, rather than keeping the handle open until your code terminates:

```
lines = File.open("host.txt") { |source| source.lines }
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Working on revising my code now based on your suggestions.  Will post back shortly my results.